# create staggering effect with useTransition on react spring

Tags: reactjs, react-spring

i'm learning react spring and i want to create a staggering effect with the useTransition hook, but the animation never goes as expected except at the first mount, pls check this link for the sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/stagger-qmtc9t?file=/src/App.js